# mPDF - Show table footer (tfoot) only once

Tags: php, yii2, mpdf, kartik-v, table-footer

I am creating a PDF file from HTML table using [Kartik's mPDF extension for Yii2](http://demos.krajee.com/mpdf).
The table footer is visible in all pages, but I want it to be shown only at the end of the entire table (in the last page).

How can I achieve this? I am using [GridView](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-grid-gridview) and [ArrayDataProvider](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-data-arraydataprovider) to create the table.

`display: table-row-group;` [is not supported by mPDF for `tfoot` element](https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/supported-css.html) and therefore is not working inside the PDF.

Comment: add some code too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come to a solution that requires the table to be changed.

Instead of using `tfoot` element for my footer I am just adding one row with footer data inside `tbody` and adding styling to that.
Since mPDF doesn't support `:last-child` selector, I had to use the supported `:nth-child()` selector:

```
$pdf->cssInline = 'tbody tr:nth-child(' . $row_count . ') td { font-weight: bold; }';
```

I set `$row_count` after adding the additional row by calling `count()` on the data array. To show correct total item count in the GridView, I added custom layout with the `$row_count` value minus 1:

```
$pdf->content = GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => $this->columns,
    'showFooter' => false,
    'layout' => '
        <div>' . Yii::t('app', 'Total <strong>{count}</strong> items.', ['count' => ($this->row_count - 1)]) . '</div>
        {items}
    '
]);
```

The resulting PDF file has correct item count before the table and properly styled "footer" only at the very end of the table.

I hope my solution is helpful for someone else. Please post an answer if you have found a better solution.